# How to record screen content from other apps on iOS? Are there security concerns regarding privacy (app sandbox)?

Tags: ios, replaykit

I'm confused. Skype announced [screen sharing for iOS](https://blogs.skype.com/news/2019/06/04/screen-sharing-goes-mobile-and-more/). This means that this app can access my screen content, including what I do in other apps, and share it with my conversation partner.

I wonder how this is possible, and whether screen sharing conflicts with the concept of the iOS [app sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/) that prevents apps to access the contents of other apps...

Answer (score 2):

Starting with iOS 11, the iOS System Broadcast (a.k.a. [ReplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit) 2) allows users to share all onscreen activity from the Control Center.

With iOS 12, the Broadcast Picker allows users to trigger screen sharing from within an app.

To protect the content of your app, assuming you don't want it captured in screen recording or broadcast live, you can check the value of `UIScreen.isCaptured` to stop media playback or hide sensitive content. The same goes for AirPlay screen mirroring with `UIScreen.screens.count > 1`.

For more information, have a look at the WWDC 2018 session
[Live Screen Broadcast with ReplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/601/).